# The first element has not yet passed through in 5000 milliseconds

Tags: scala, akka, microservices, runtimeexception, lagom

I am new to lagom scala. Created a simple crud to learn the key concept of it. First I compiled my code using `sbt clean compile` and it successfully compiled the code.
After that I tried to run the project using `sbt clean runAll` command. Sometimes service started without any problem. But sometimes I found a message saying that

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The first element has not yet passed through in 5000 milliseconds.
    at akka.stream.impl.Timers$Initial$$anon$1.onTimer(Timers.scala:62)
    at akka.stream.stage.TimerGraphStageLogic.onInternalTimer(GraphStage.scala:1601)
    at akka.stream.stage.TimerGraphStageLogic.$anonfun$getTimerAsyncCallback$1(GraphStage.scala:1590)
    at akka.stream.stage.TimerGraphStageLogic.$anonfun$getTimerAsyncCallback$1$adapted(GraphStage.scala:1590)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.runAsyncInput(GraphInterpreter.scala:466)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:497)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:599)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:768)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:783)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:534)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:532)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:690)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:573)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:543)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:269)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:230)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone please explain me the solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @md sam, welcome to SO, please, provide the code in order than others can help you.

Comment: I observed that it happens when multiple task I was doing in my system at the same time. I am not sure that this could be the reason for showing above message.

Comment: @aironman I have lagom project with service api and impl. I do not know which code I should provide here.

Comment: Hi!, I never did anything with Lagom project, so I can't help you, but if nobody can help you here in SO, you can ask too in https://gitter.im/lagom/lagom?at=5e4faeaba0aa6629f5e1db9d

Answer (score 1):

I think that is one of the offset-timeouts, either for the [read side](https://github.com/lagom/lagom/blob/4497f205be7f82613f1bd287710435326e76d6c7/persistence/core/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L55) or for the [Kafka client](https://github.com/lagom/lagom/blob/4497f205be7f82613f1bd287710435326e76d6c7/service/core/kafka/client/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L30).

If you are running everything on one machine and it is struggling, getting things running, setting up connections etc. could potentially take more time, so try tweaking those timeouts to higher values and see if it helps.

Comment: How to set timeouts to higher values?

Comment: Put those linked settings in your `application.conf`